# SQLite with android not adding column

Tags: android, sqlite, alter-table

I read some threads about topics similar to this one however I could not find any big information on it. I am trying to add a column to the existing database table, and read from it on the content provider class, but it is not going thru, on the DBHelper class I do the ALTER TABLE as follows

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion<2) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE SongInfo ADD COLUMN playcount INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }       
}
```

my version number is 1, and when I run it it gets the column playcount does not exist, I am trying to get the column by calling for it on contentProvider class, is there something else to it? do I need to update in another part of the code or is it suppose to accept the ALTER TABLE and just make the column readable from start of program, thanks much.

Comment: did you try adding `;` in the end of your sql statement?

Comment: yes and it does the same, is there a way to just make that alteration and check physically on the table if it was done? I know on the emulator you can check the DDMS but where can I look for the table inside my cell phone...

Comment: @AndreyArias you can just run a query to return all results from the table if you wish to view its contents. No need to try and actually view it in the phone. On a more related note, I have had this problem before and could not solve it. Rather than update the existing table I was forced to drop table and recreate. It was not fun

Comment: so, you used DROP TABLE and then created the table from scratch by calling onCreate and adding the extra column you wanted? if that is what I am getting

Comment: After you run the query to retrieve all results from the table you can do this to check if the column has been created: if (cursor.getColumnIndex("playcount") >= 0) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

try

```
db.beginTransaction();
db.execSQL("...");
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

Comment: no luck with that piece of code, the problem I am having is when trying to retrieve it from ContentProvider, it does not have that column available

Comment: try setting breakpoint on db.execSQL() line.  May be you DB is already version 2?

Comment: no luck with anything, is there an additional line of code I have to write anywhere else to make the table writable for the code to execute well? I have the DBHelper class and the ContentProvider class

Comment: I am a bit suspicious about this text: "my version number is 1, and when I run it it gets the column playcount does not exist, I am trying to get the column by calling for it on contentProvider class".  What does it mean "I am trying to get the column by calling for it on contentProvider class"?  Client code (UI) preferably should use ContentResolver.  Have you changed the version number of you database from 1 to 2?  When you do, onUpgrade will run automatically.

Comment: kill me please, I just changed the version number variable from 1 to 2 and it worked.... thanks much!!

Comment: Glad it was helpful Andrey!